# If a Macbook has TRIM support, does this mean it automatically uses TRIM command on deleted files?

Tags: ssd, sata, trim

Under SATA/SATA Express in my System Information, I have "Yes" for TRIM support, so I assume TRIM has been enabled for my Mac. Does this mean that every time I delete a file, the TRIM command is used on those files, or do I have to invoke TRIM myself to use it?

Comment: Running trim by hand may have been necessary on third-party SSDs about 10 years ago, but there's very little on your Mac that needs 'managing' to this level of detail.

Answer (score 1):

When trim is enabled you have nothing to do and the trim mechanism is operational on all ssd internal disk and external ssd in thunderbolt enclosure.
For the ssd Apple you have nothing to do, Trim is enabled automatically. On other ssd you have to enable trim with the terminal command :

`sudo trimforce enable`

Comment: So simply emptying one's Trash will perform TRIM on them?

Comment: Trim is a global mechanism : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)